# nestedrecyclerview inside recyclerview not scrolling android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/settings"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:background="@mipmap/menu" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_12sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="2019"
                android:textColor="#EDF0F5"
                android:textSize="19dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/addPeople"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"/>
        </LinearLayout>     
        <android.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/l1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
            <android.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_item"    
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_7sdp"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>    
    <include layout="@layout/listhome" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

i written above xml code in my application recyclerview showing but not scrolling if i add nestedscrollview android i written above xml code in my application recyclerview showing but not scrolling if i add nestedscrollview android

Comment: You don't need to put recycler view in a nested scroll view when you don't have multiple scroll views.

Answer (score 0):

You're nesting a recycler view inside another scrollable viewgroup i.e. `NestedScrollView`, Both have there own scroll mechanisms but since parent is `NestedScrollView` the child `RecyclerView` will loose its ability to scroll properly.

Solution to your problem is just disabling nested scrolling on recycler view.

Try this:

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recyclerView,false);
```

Comment: ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recyclerView,false); i added this code but not scrolling

Comment: If you've properly initialized the `RecyclerView` and have called `ViewCompact.setNestedScrollingEnabled` than you view might have been blocked/covered or overlayed by some other view, which might have consumed the touch, can't say much without seeing the complete code snippet